# Unconfirmed bitcoin transaction for more than 3 days

Tags: lost-bitcoins

i sent bitcoins on 14.3.2016. the amount has been debited from my wallet but remains unconfirmed. i am waiting for the transaction to go through but maybe because i checked try and sent with 0 transaction fees the transaction is not being confirmed. i want to know how to get the bitcoins back and whether there is some way that a beginner like me can stop the unconfirmed transaction so that the coins are returned to my wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retract a transaction. If it fails, the Bitcoins will be credited back to your wallet since Bitcoins can't be lost.

Chances are high the the transaction will pass. Even with a fee of zero. I suppose you'll have to wait another 2-3 days.

I advise using Bitcoin-XT instead of Bitcoin-QT so we won't get insane transaction fee amounts and limited transaction volume per block in the future.

Comment: the transaction got confirmed today even though it had a 0 fee.

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance you can stop transaction which already sent. You can only wait and yes.. your bitcoin will return into your wallet if transaction failed.

Failed can cause many things, one of that things is take too long to confirm and you can't send or asking people to help you without cost nothing :)